# Grub does not fit the screen

Tags: boot, grub

I have a problem with my grub installation. The screen is "moved" to the left a couple of pixels, which means that I cannot read the first 20 or so characters of the entries when I boot.

I'm running: Grub 1.99.21-ubuntu (the system is a Kubuntu 12.04). My video card is a Radeon HD 5400, running @ 1920x1080. My monitor, if it makes a difference is a Samsung SyncMaster P2470HN . When the boot process start itself (with the kubuntu log) the screen fits normally. Also, my other terminals (TTY1-6) suffers from the same problems.

Comment: is grub coming up with a 80x25 screen like the startup screen of your bios? If not you might be running grub with text in graphics mode.

Comment: You're not using a VGA cable are you? (Should be DVI or HDMI)

Comment: This can be either a bad, or less than compatible, VGA cable, or simply a need for tuning on the monitor side. If it has an autoconfiguration feature, try it while the GRUB menu is showing up. If the normal video mode of your OS looks OK, it is probably just lack of configuration for that mode.

Comment: I'm using a DVI cable but wit a VGA adapter at the computer.
@Anthon It is coming as 1920x1080, but it is to the left. Meaning part of the screen is hidden, and to the right I have a black strip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your monitor syncing the analog signal (you are using VGA at the computer side). I recommend editing (as root) /etc/default/grub and inserting (or uncommenting) the line:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

After that you have to run `sudo update-grub`

That will reduce your grub screen to 80x25 characters, but like with the BIOS messages, your monitor is more likely to be able to sync.

**If** your computer can handle digital DVI (your monitor is almost certainly being able to handle that), I would highy recommend investing in a digital DVI cable. In my experience that solves syncing problems and seems to be giving a sharper picture.

Comment: Thanks Anthon. I will search for a compatible DVI-I cable (couldn't find before)